# How to crop a square at the exact centre of an image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

Given a square image, how can I crop, at the exact center, of the image?

What if the image is not square itself?

What if I'm using Photoshop CS6 or some older version? 
Is the procedure the same?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your image is **not** square:

1. Choose `View > New Guide` then tick the `Vertical` option and enter
   `50%` in the box and click `OK`.
2. Choose `View > New Guide` then tick the `Horizontal` option and
   enter `50%` in the box and click `OK`.

This provides a guide intersection at the image center.

3. Grab the **Marquee Selection Tool** or the **Crop Tool**, hold down the
   <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click-drag
   starting at that center guide intersection.

This draws a square selection (crop area) at the center of the image.

4. Then simply choose `Image > Crop`, or hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> to commit the crop (if using the crop tool)

---

If the image itself **is** square...

1. Choose `Select > All` from the menu.
2. Then choose `Select > Modify > Contract`
3. Tick the `Apply effect from Canvas Bounds` box and enter the amount
   of offset, from the canvas edge, you want and click `OK`.
4. Then simply choose `Image > Crop`

---

For versions of Photoshop where "contract" may not be available after selecting all, use the first method.

Comment: At the exact centre of an image

Comment: Is the image itself square? More info in the question wouldn't hurt :)

Comment: Sorry :) Yes, it is

Comment: I cannot choose Contract when everything is selected. In any case, thanks for your help. I just find a bit crazy that this apparently simple operation must be such a pain...

Comment: You must be using an older version of Photoshop... Again, more info in the question is **never** a bad thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple method that works in all programs is to add another layer, and create a line from the upper left to the lower right corners, and the same for upper right to lower left. You can then select all, scale selection, and line it up on these lines. This will crop to the same aspect ratio, with a different overall size.

Like this:
[image]

While hardly being an elegant solution, it has the advantage of working on any platform.